# Entity reference item list with preview images?

Tags: entities

In a node type 'album' I have an entity reference field 'photo' that can be used to reference nodes of the type 'single_photo'. This works fine – using the module [Entityreference view widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_view_widget) lets the editor choose nodes from a lst view with a preview image and optional additional fields:

[image]

The actual list of referenced nodes however does only show the node title:

[image]

I now would like to have a similar preview in the actual item list – or maybe even also use other fields of the referenced nodes. Is there a similar module or a combination of views and code or the like, that would provide such a functionality? Any pointers, suggestions, links would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a big problem - what would you want to see as "preview" of a node? If your nodes contains image field called preview, it might be doable. Rendering nodes to images on the fly is hardly feasible, it require some kind of browser engine available on the server. So how do you imagine your preview images uploaded / created?

Comment: I wouldn't want a 'real preview' of the actual node. Instead an option to add fields to the list (as Entityreference view widget provides it for the node selection) would be very helpful. So replacing the default item list with a custom list (view) is currently what I'm looking for – but of course I would also try any other option if there is any…

Answer (score 1):

The [Entity Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser) module almost does exactly this (for Drupal 8). The module allows you to create a view display (it adds a new Entity Browser display type) to select items and it also allows you to, via a configuration on the referencing entity's Form Display screen, display a referenced entity's view mode on the edit screen.